# How to create Rails Dynamic Radio Button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radio-button

iam new to rails in my view page i used f.radio_button :answer for multiple choice question .

This is my html code

```
<% @questions.each do |q| %>
<%= q.questionText %>
<%= f.radio_button :answer, "1" %><%= q.answerA %>
<%= f.radio_button :answer, "2" %><%= q.answerB %>
<%= f.radio_button :answer, "3" %><%= q.answerC %>
<%= f.radio_button :answer, "4" %><%= q.answerD %>
<% end %>
```

In  this :answer should be increment dynamically for each question. 
     Like this code
    question 1  :answer1
                :answer1
                :answer1
                :answer1
    question 2  :answer2
                :answer2
                :answer2
                :answer2

Please give some suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can try soomthing like this

<% @questions.each_with_index do |q, i| %>
<%= q.questionText %>
<%= f.radio_button "answer#{i+1}", "1" %><%= q.answerA %>
<%= f.radio_button "answer#{i+1}", "2" %><%= q.answerB %>
<%= f.radio_button "answer#{i+1}", "3" %><%= q.answerC %>
<%= f.radio_button "answer#{i+1}", "4" %><%= q.answerD %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: In controller how can i get which answer is selected for each question. Like params[:answer]

Comment: got it in controller too... Thanks for your valuable time .